# My session of auth.js returns name and mail and img and id but when i use the id in client side it returns undfined

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

My session of auth.js returns name and mail and img and id but when I use the id on the client side it returns undefined
I am using Next.js MongoDB and auth.js
I want the ID to be put on the URL And it is not secured to use mail-in mail I think
So can You give me a solution?

I expacted that i can use the id on client side but it always returns undefined

Comment: If you are referring to the _id, that is usually and ObjectId in the database, but when you include that in the URL, it is sent as string.  Since mongodb comparisons are type-sensitive, that won't work unless you convert the string to ObjectId first.

Comment: Can you add the necessary code to have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?